# Quarto + Julia: stack size exceeded error on MacOS

Tags: macos, julia, quarto

Here is a MWE that errors out on MacOS:

````
---
title: "Plots Demo"
author: "ITA"
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
jupyter: julia-1.9
---

## Test plots

```{julia}
#| label: fig-errors
#| fig-cap: "Plotting causes stack exceeded error - MacOS"

using Plots
plotly()

dat = rand(1200, 68)
plot(dat)
```
````

On running `quarto preview test.qmd` the error that occurs is:

```
ERROR: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

What could be the reason for this error? I am using Quarto 1.3.361 on Ventura 13.4. Is the process running out of memory or just out of locations on the stack? Is there an environment variable to allow increasing the size of the call stack?

I tried wrapping the `plot` in a function as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71991634/6395452) but I still get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that this error is raised by the underlying Javascript engine Deno. The fix is to set the environment variable

`QUARTO_DENO_EXTRA_OPTIONS=--v8-flags=--stack-size=xxxx`

to an appropriate size. The default size is `864` (not sure why that particular number).

On my machine `ulimit -a` reports 8176 kbytes so on setting the `v8` flag to the same; the error disappeared. It would be nice to set it this value automatically in `_quarto.yml` on a per project basis but one can just use [`direnv`](https://direnv.net/) or something as well.